# How to get dictionary key value in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, dictionary

I have filled A1..A3 with the values K01,K02 and K03
B1 .. B3 are filled with values "Cost 1", "Cost 2" and "Cost 3"

A1 to B3 are used as a dictionary by selecting A1 .. B3 then Insert>Name>Create

When in cell A7 the value '=K01_' is filled, the displayed value is "Cost 1".
If i enter the formula '=MATCH("K01";A1:A3)' in B7 the result is 1.
So far so good.

Now i do want the use the value in A1 to be used in the MATCH formula. But this does not work as i expected. When entering the formula '=MATCH(A7;A1:A3)' in C7 it does return a #N/A.

How can i use the actual name in a cell in a formula ?

Comment: perhaps because in cell A1 you have "K01" and in cell A7 "K01_" , however some carefully laid out text showing what you are trying to achieve would help people help you...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by using `=MATCH(MID(FORMULATEXT(A7);2;3);A1:A3)`

Comment: Please *explain* this answer so that it will be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I don't have the reputation to comment. You want the value in A1 to be used in the MATCH formula. Shouldn't your formula be like this: `=MATCH(A1, A1:A3)`

Or did you mean this: `=MATCH(A7, B1:B3)`

If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: Corrected it. Cell A7 is assigned '=K01_'. Because it is referencing a name, A7 shows 'Cost 1'.
The formula MID(FORMULATEXT(A7);2;3) returns 'K01' which is used to match a value in A1..A3 returning '1'